# Вывод двумерных массивов в php

Tags: php, массивы

Код формирования массива

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++){
        array_push($temp_arr, $i + $j);
    }
    array_push($arr, $temp_arr);
    $temp_arr = [];
}
```

В итоге получается массив:

```
0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5
2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6
3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7
4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8
```

Есть два варианта вывода этого массива:

1 вариант

```
foreach($arr as $items) {
  foreach($items as $item) {
    echo $item.'-';
  }
  echo "<br>";
}
```

2 вариант

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  for ($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++) {
    echo $arr[i][j].'-';
  }
}
```

Причем работает только первый вариант. Почему нельзя обращаться по индексу для вывода, но в то же время такой код работает?

```
$arr[3][2] = 10;
```

В чем прикол? Или я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: А вы пробовали индексы не константами, а переменными сделать? У вас очепятка, надо так: `$arr[$i][$j]`

Comment: А чтобы таких проблем не было, надо логи смотреть, там проблема сразу обозначена была

Comment: итишкина итишка....спасибо..после решетки не удобно на пыхе,постоянно забываю про этот доллар =( спасибо

Comment: используйте редактор с подсветкой php кода либо ide, и данная проблема исчезнет. а вообще когда привыкните к этому знаку будете указывать его в названии переменных в других языках)

Comment: хреново))))опять тупые ошибки будут.....мне просто привычней работать в блокноте(относительно веба).может плагин можете подсказать подходящий для такого случая?)

Comment: @DarkVss, [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) или [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) - те же блокноты, только намного продвинутее. И подсветка кода есть, и плагины можно оставить. Если IDE не хотите, то хотя бы попробуйте sublime (npp попроще будет и не такой продвинутый)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как ВОРОН отметил в комментарии, в PHP переменные пишутся с `$` в начале.  Вот это должно работать:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  for ($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++) {
    echo $arr[$i][$j].'-';
  }
}
```